# How to attach file of OTG (Pen drive) to email?

Tags: android

I am new in android i want to attach files programatically in android Studio code of OTG(pen drive) to email. I am able to get files and directory of OTG (pen drive) .

Comment: If you can get files and directories from a pen drive then attaching them to an email is the same as with other files. So i do not understand your problem.

Comment: I am not able to get path of the file of pen drive so i am unable to attach it to email

Comment: `I am able to get files and directory of OTG (pen drive) .` ???? Well why are you telling you can?

Answer (score 0):

first, try Pendrive in a laptop. If your pen drive contains bad sectors it's complicated.
and also try to use original OTG cable of your mobile manufacturer.